# Reduce Size of Standard Persistent Disk of 500GB to 50GB?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a VM instance running on Windows Server. It has a SPD of 500GB. I couldn't reduce it. I can only enlarge this. This happen because I am having an impression that if Digital Ocean can increase/decrease, then Google Compute should be able to do the same. I am totally wrong.

1. How can I reduce the size? Is there any easier way to do so?
2. Will the feature available soon?

Any advise are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud providers generally only allow disk expansion, disallowing disk shrinking. This is done because, when shrinking disks, data loss is a very probable outcome.

If you need a smaller disk, the better option probably is to spin up a new VM/disk, then migrate your data to it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am thinking of create a new smaller SPD and migrate the data there. But, I am not sure how to do it. My VM is now running on single SPD (500GB).